# Checking if the query is empty does not work

Tags: plugin-development, query

I hope you have a good day.
I get a query from the database,
If the query is empty, the message "Register" will be displayed
Otherwise, the message "Register" will be displayed
See the code below and please guide me.
*Nothing is displayed when the query is empty*

```
function book_user(){
    global $wpdb;
    $rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `quy` FROM wp_course_management WHERE user.current_user = '$booked_username' AND `quy` > 0");
    foreach($rows as $row){
      if (empty($row->quy)){
        echo "register.";
            }
      else{
        echo "You have alredy registered.";
        };}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query includes a test for `quy` to be non-zero, so you will never run into the situation where `empty($row->quy)` will be `true`. Furthermore, you should be testing if `$rows` is set or is `null` since you indicated that *"nothing is displayed when the query is empty."*

You will need to rewrite your code to test the result of the query to test for the `null` condition. If it is `null`, then the user is registered. Otherwise, they are not registered.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is displayed because `echo "register."` is never reached, which is because foreach is never run due to there being nothing in $rows to iterate.

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `quy` FROM wp_course_management WHERE user.current_user = '$booked_username' AND `quy` > 0");
if (!$rows){
    echo "Register.";
}else{
    echo "You have already registered.";
}
```

or

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `quy` FROM wp_course_management WHERE user.current_user = '$booked_username' AND `quy` > 0");
echo $rows? "You have already registered." : "Register.";
```

Comment: Thank you both for your guidance.

Comment: @FardadFarhang if this answer solves it please mark it as correct